# Mathematical text for Astrophysics

Tags: mathematical-physics, astrophysics, resource-recommendations

Please recommend me some Mathematical text books and a list of Mathematical topics for Astrophysics.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie, Actually I want to learn a background math for learning Astrophysics

Comment: For the most part, you would just need to know algebra, trigonometry, and differential & integral calculus.

Comment: Thank you very much, and please recommend me some math textbooks

Comment: My suggestion, I suppose would be to search Amazon.com for those keywords & buy whatever fits your price range & rating level.